# Optaplanner planning variable is NOT nullable BUT still assign to null

Tags: optaplanner, drools-planner

planning variable is NOT nullable. when I print out planning entity in variable listener for my shadow value, still in planning process NULL value still assign to planning variable??

planning entity:

```
 // Planning variables: changes during planning, between score calculations.
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"numberRange"})
    private Integer number;

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "numberRange")
    private List<Integer> numberRange;

    @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = BoxUpdatingVariableListener.class,
            sources = {@PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "number")})
    private Integer shaodowNumber;
```

variable listener:

```
 protected void updateShadowNumber(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, Box sourceBox) {
        System.out.println("number:"+sourceBox.getNumber());
    }
```

part of result:

```
02:24:46.832 [main        ] INFO  Solving started: time spent (74), best score (-3init/-90), environment mode (FULL_ASSERT), random (JDK with seed 0).
number:1
number:null
number:2
number:null
number:3
number:null
number:4
number:null
number:5
number:null
number:6
number:null
number:7
number:null
number:7
number:7
number:null
number:null
02:24:46.883 [main        ] DEBUG     CH step (0), time spent (125), score (-2init/-43), selected move count (7), picked move (Box-1 {null -> 7}).
number:1
number:null
number:2
number:null
number:3
number:null
number:4
number:null
number:5
number:null
number:6
number:null
number:6
number:7
number:6
number:null
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually the result of not running a construction phase

https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.14.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#constructionHeuristics

like this for example

```html
<constructionHeuristic>
  <constructionHeuristicType>STRONGEST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
</constructionHeuristic>
```

Comment: thank you for ur reply. so how to avoid null variable assignment?